# What's the difference between 'on the train' and 'by train?'

Tags: grammar, prepositions

While studying, I faced these two sentences:

> I come to Istanbul on the train every week.

and

> I came to Istanbul last week by train.

I want to know is there any differences between the phrases  'on the train' and 'by the train?'

Regards

Comment: Idiomatically, it's *I go there **by train** every day,* not *...by **the** train*. But this belongs on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) anyway.

Comment: ...but I suppose we ELU users might occupy ourselves wondering why [***come here on** the train*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22come+here+on+the+train%22) should be way more than twice as common as [*come here **by** train*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22come+here+by+train%22), whereas [***go there by** train*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22go+there+by+train%22) and [*go there **on** the train*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22go+there+on+the+train%22) are both equally common.

Comment: First, I agree that both are correct: simply, ‘on the train’ tells me what you were on while you were getting there, while ‘by train’ tells me the method you used to travel.  Why should ‘on’ be more common?  If you think language is subject to natural selection, there does not need to be a reason.  Somehow it caught on. Note how (I think) we travel BY plane or BY sea.  We go BY car but (more commonly, I think ON THE BUS.  Where did that ‘the’ come from?

Comment: need to include 'under the train' too. lol

Answer (score 1):

*On* means you are physically on the train. *By* is referring to the method you used to get to Istanbul (ie train).

Comment: Just so: you ride *on the* [or *a*] *train* to get to your destination *by train*.   You can also use *on the* or *on a*, and *by* with other modes of transportation: bus, car, bicycle, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Both phrases mean the same thing. In my area of the US, they are used interchangeably.

It is always 'by train' and never 'by the train' though.

The phrase 'by the train' would mean the same as 'near the train'---quite a difference in meaning. A native speaker would probably recognize the mistake in context, as it is a common mistake for non-native speakers.