# Difference between 'went home by taxi' and 'went home in a taxi'

Tags: word-usage

What is the difference between by and in? For example:

- I went home ***by*** taxi.
- I went home ***in*** a taxi.

Is there any difference?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between 'on the train' and 'by train?'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/458586/whats-the-difference-between-on-the-train-and-by-the-train)

Comment: "By taxi" allows for the possibility that several different taxis were involved.

Comment: 'By boat / ferry / car / bike / train / plane / taxi / bus ...' are the standard expressions, showing agency (type of transport used). 'In a car', 'in a taxi', 'on the bus', 'on the train', 'on the ferry', and 'on a (or my) bike' are also idiomatic, and while being synonymous with their counterparts, hint more at the specifications of the transport, the layout (why we say 'on the train' has been addressed before). So "John, Jane and I went home **in a** taxi", hinting at the shared space, might be the more common choice.  Go 'by' and 'on foot' are very closely synonymous.

Comment: If you have been out drinking with friends, the expressions can have slightly different connotations. If someone *went home by taxi*, the implication is that they did so actively, having made a conscious choice of means while still relatively sober. If they *went home in a taxi*, you open the possibility of them being loaded into a taxi by friends. It’s a more passive expression.